# classify amount list and currency list code from s list

Tags: python, regex

I have below list:

```
list_a = ['USD', 'Notional Amount:', 'USD', '50,000,000.00', 'KRW', 'Notional Amount:', 'KRW', '53,585,000,000']
```

`list_a` include Currency code like `'usd'` and amount like `50,000,000.00`
By using python, I want to classify following:

```
am_list = [50000000,53585000000]
cu_list = ['USD','USD','KRW' 'KRW']
```

Anyone who will solve it easily give me solution please.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing platform. Please, show your attempts and come with a specific problem if you encounter any.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, since it has an accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over it and check the type of element:

```
import re

list_a = ['USD', 'Notional Amount:', 'USD', '50,000,000.00', 'KRW', 'Notional Amount:', 'KRW', '53,585,000,000']

am_list  = []
cu_list  = []
for element in list_a:
    # if element is number like combination of "number" and "," and "."
    if re.match('^[\d\.,]+$', element):
        am_list.append(element)
    # curency symble 2 or 3 letters
    if re.match('^[A-Z]{2,3}$', element):
        cu_list.append(element)

print(am_list) # ['50,000,000.00', '53,585,000,000']
print(cu_list) # ['USD', 'USD', 'KRW', 'KRW']
```

If you want to make sure it's a valid amount that looks like this : `'50,000,000.00', '50.00', '50,000.00', '50' ... etc`:

```
   re.match('^(\d+,)*\d+(\.\d+)?$', element)
```

Comment: and if you want to complicate things to much is a valid amount: `'^(\d+,)*\d+(\.\d+)?$'` this will do it